# Receiving an error when uninstall

Tags: commerce, 8

I am getting a WSOD after attempting to uninstall the Drupal Commerce module on Drupal 8.1.1 Has anyone seen this error before, and possibly point me a direction? Lost trying to fix this.

> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "commerce_product" entity type does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition() (line 125 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php).

Comment: Did you remove the module directory before running the uninstall command?

Answer (score 0):

Commerce for Drupal 8 must be considered unusable at this stage and very unstable as it is still in alpha version.

No stable version has been released yet, therefore it is advised not to try to build anything yet with it, and installation shall be considered for development purpose only.